# How to call constructor of the current class and parent class at the same time?

Tags: c#

```
public class A{
    List m;
    public A(int a, int b) {m=new List(); ...}
}


public class B : A{
    List a;
    List b;
    public B(){...}  //constructor1
    public B(int a, int b) : base(a,b){...} //constructor2
}
```

My question is I need to initialize both list a and b in class B. If I put them in the constructor1, how can I call constructor1 in constructor2? I don't want to rewrite the initialization statements in constructor2 again. Thanks!

Comment: Why not make a method to initialize the `List`'s and call them from both constructors?

Comment: Delegating to a method doesn't let you initialize `readonly` members, but I guess Siegfried hasn't indicated that he wants them readonly.

Comment: Yeah, I just tried that. So in theory, it is not possible to call both the constructor from the current class and that from the parent class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds to me that you simply have the dependency backwards mentally. I think what you want to do is this:

```
public class B : A {
    List _a;
    List _b;

    public B(int a, int b) : base(a, b) {
        // this calls the base constructor

        // presumably you're initializing _a and _b in here?
        _a = new List();
        _b = new List();
    }

    // let x and y be your defaults for a and b
    public B() : this(x, y) {
        // this calls the this(a, b) constructor,
        // which in turn calls the base constructor
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put them in constructor2 and have constructor1 call constructor2?  Or initialize them inline instead of in the constructor?  There's lots of ways to skin this cat.

Answer (score 1):

If you have initialization activities that have to happen in multiple constructors, put them into a separate private method, and call that method from any constructor that needs those activities.  I do not understand what the parent's constructor has to do with it, or why you would want to call one constructor from another.

Comment: I just modified my question, actually there is another initialization in class A.